# Google App Engine Error (The requested URL / was not found on this server)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a simple web application that says Hello Udacity and upload it to Google App Engine, but I keep on getting a bunch of errors.

**Error message from Google App Engine:**

```
11:57 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Error parsing yaml file:
Unable to assign value 'udacityassignment2' to attribute 'url':
Value 'udacityassignment2' for url does not match expression '^(?:(?!\^)/.*|\..*|(\(.).*(?!\$).)$'
  in "C:\Users\Wealthy\Desktop\ambhelloworld\udacityassignment2\app.yaml", line 12, column 8
2013-05-27 23:57:00 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

**app.yaml:**

```
application: udacityassignment2
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: udacityassignment2
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

**main.py:**

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello Udacity!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

**Google App Engine console:**

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

Any assistance on how to correct this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The error is indicating that the `url` entry in your app.yaml is not valid. Try this

```
url: /udacityassignment2
```

And as Tim pointed, the mapping should be

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/udacityassignment2', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: In addition the mapping in the WSGI handler for app doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the URL entry as below to give you more flexibility when creating your url routing table

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```